# How protozoa spawns in newly formed ponds?

Tags: microbiology

How big protozoa like Paramecium caudatum, Amoeba proteus, Euglena viridis etc. appear in newly created ponds of water? Suppose there was rain, and pond was formed. Or earth, dead leaves, live leaves and wood was added to bottle like in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2T__l7FgU4

She says in this video that paramecium "should spawn from the dirt", but this makes no sense to me... Do they magically recombine from inorganic elements? Doubtful. Or maybe they are just scattered in every grain of dirt, everywhere, in a form of microbial cyst? Seems not very realistic either...

P.S. I'm mostly interested how Paramecium caudatum get in there, but if other protozoa have some other means, that would be interesting too.

Comment: Life does not generate spontaneously. Period.

Comment: Maybe the dirt include cysts and spores?